# How to check when battery gets 100% charged?

Tags: android, android-service

This is the function which I have at the moment which is exexcuted when a button on UI is clicked & it shows the string str (the status of charging) on the TextView.

```
public void checkStatus (View view) {
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Context context = this;
    Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    // Are we charging / charged?
    int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int perc = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

    String str;
    if (perc == 100) {
        str = "Fully charged";
    } else if (isCharging) {
        str = "Charging";
    } else {
        str = "Not Charging";
    }

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textview.setText(str);
}
```

Now what I want to do is to check the battery periodically & once it is 100% (fully charged) then to call a function, let's call it DiscntCharger()

From my research, I need to use IntentService here for monitoring the charging status & once it finds that battery is fully charged, it needs to call the function in my main activity. However, since I am fairly new to android development, I am unable to understand how I can implement that.

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
In your activity class create a broadcast reciever and do anything when battery gets full

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
      textview.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
      //  do your stuff here
    }
  };
```

and in onCreate() register broadcast class

```
registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Monitoring the Battery Level and Charging State](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a `BroadcastReceiver` to achieve what you want.

1. Add the receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. Write the `BroadcastReceiver`

   ```
   public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
          boolean isFull = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
          // Do your job after checking for isFull
       }
   }
   ```

Read more about it over here: [Monitoring Device Battery Status](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

Point to note:
With Android O you might to need to shift to `JobScheduler` or `JobDispatcher` so read about it here [Background Services in Android O](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-handle-background-services-in-android-o-f96783e65268)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set up a broadcast receiver.

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html